When to use PCA(n_components=0.95) and when to use PCA(n_components=2), what is the difference between them?
For the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) model training
when to pass variance as PCA(n_components=0.95) and when to use PCA(n_components=2) with pipeline having Standardscaler for standardizes the feature values.

pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    PCA(n_components=0.95)  # Retain 95% of the variance
)



pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    PCA(n_components=2)  # Reduce to exactly 2 dimensions
)

When to Use Each
Use n_components=0.95:

When you are dealing with datasets with high dimensionality and you want to reduce the number of features while retaining most of the information.
When preparing data for machine learning algorithms to improve efficiency and reduce overfitting.
When you need to understand the principal components that capture most of the variance in your data.

Use n_components=2:

When you need to visualize the data in 2 dimensions.
When the task requires a fixed number of dimensions, such as certain clustering algorithms or when creating 2D representations for human interpretation.

